# Have Cors error just for Post request in ASP.NET Web API on .NET 4.8

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-4.8

I have an ASP.NET Web API project with .NET 4.8, for accepting requests from any origin, I added these lines to the `web.config`:

```
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="*" />
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="*"/>
```

When I send request by axios in React, I don't have any problem for GET request, but for POST request I have this error:

> Access to fetch at 'API URL' from origin 'http://localhost:5173' has
> been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't
> pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.